# How to use select drop menu with json

Tags: php, json, select

I want to have a select drop down menu with this script : [LINK](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

I have a script which is already making me json formatted data and I would like to use same one to fill 2 menus. For example I want to have 2 menus which will have `driver` and `cars`

This is the script:

```
echo '{ "results" : [ ';

$gettruck_result = dbMySql::Exec(.........query.........);
$result_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gettruck_result)){

  $row_object = '{';
  $row_object .= '"id": "' . $row['id'] . '", ';
  $row_object .= '"driver": "' . $row['drivers'] . '", ';
  $row_object .= '"trucks": "' . $row['trucks'] . '", ';
  $row_object .= '}';    
  $result_array[] = $row_object;
}
$result_str = implode(", ", $result_array);
echo $result_str;
echo " ] }";
?>
```

This is what they have in the documentation :

```
[{text:'Lorem', value:'5', title:'icons/enabled.gif'},{text:'Ipsum', value:'6',title:'icons/enabled.gif'}]
```

I would like to have something like:
1. When you load driver's : `text` should be driver's name, `value` should be id and `title` would be a some picture
2. When you load trucks : `text` should be trucks name, `value` should be id and `title` is different icon.

Can I do this in the same time with calling the script only once?

Answer (score 1):

You know there is a php function to encode an object/array to a json?

json_encode http://www.php.net/json_encode

I think the easiest way is to:
1) provide a nestedjson structure like this:

```
drivers {
    text: 'Lorem',
    value: '5',
    title: 'icons/enabled.gif',
    trucks: {
        text: 'Ipsum',
        value: '4',
        title: 'icons/foo.gif',

...
```

2) another option is to make an ajax call when a user selects a driver. The return of this ajax call holds all trucks for that specific driver.

Comment: I need a list of all drivers in one select menu and all the trucks in another menu

Comment: then provide two json strings.

Comment: I need to fill everything with one json call

Comment: If you can only make one AJAX call, it seems that you don't even need AJAX.  Have PHP create *n* select boxes, 1 for each driver, each containing the trucks assigned to that driver, initially hide them all, then display / hide them as necessary.